# Delete the last number from a row in R

Tags: database, dataframe, dataset

I have the following dataset and I wish to delete the last number from each row:

```
id_municipio       
 1 5300108
 2 5300108
 3 5300108
```

I would like to transform it into:

```
id_municipio       
 1 530010
 2 530010
 3 530010
```

All the rows have 7 numbers, and I want to delete the last one to transform it into a 6 number length.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which programming language you use and which type your column has. Assuming you use python and the column is an integer type, you can use this approach:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id_municipio': [5300108, 5300108, 5300108]})
df['id_municipio'] = df['id_municipio'].astype(str).str[:-1].astype(int)
```

If it's a str type column, the approach can be reduced to:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id_municipio': ['5300108', '5300108', '5300108']})
df['id_municipio'] = df['id_municipio'].str[:-1]
```

Comment: Thanks! I forget to say that I am using R. Can you make it using R?